# Intermittent exception in Google Cloud function when connecting to Cloud SQL (Mysql)

Tags: java, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

```
Failed to update metadata for Cloud SQL instance.
at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance.addExceptionContext (CloudSqlInstance.java:455)
at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance.fetchMetadata (CloudSqlInstance.java:322)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly (TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run (InterruptibleTask.java:69)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run (TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:515)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: readHandshakeRecord
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord (SSLSocketImpl.java:1320)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:411)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect (HttpsClient.java:567)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute (NetHttpRequest.java:148)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute (NetHttpRequest.java:84)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute (HttpRequest.java:1012)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:549)
```

another one

```
Failed to create ephemeral certificate for the Cloud SQL instance. at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance.addExceptionContext(CloudSqlInstance.java:455) at 
com.google.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance.fetchEphemeralCertificate(CloudSqlInstance.java:341) at 
com.google.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance.lambda$performRefresh$0(CloudSqlInstance.java:204) at 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125) at 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69) at 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: readHandshakeRecord 
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1320) 
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:411) 
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567) 
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) 
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1367) 
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1342) 
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246) 
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113) 
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84) 
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012) 
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:549) 
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:482) 
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:599) 
at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance.fetchEphemeralCertificate(CloudSqlInstance.java:339) ... 10 more Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed) at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110) at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81) at
```

**I am getting this exceptions when accessing cloudsql(mysql)  from my cloud function**

I am using com.zaxxer.hikari.* package for connection pooling and management. Have read that these exceptions can be ignored in one of the posts as these are created while retrying, how ever they are far too frequent and we might not be able to know the end user experience and if these can be ignored or not.

Request your assistance

Comment: How do you connect your Cloud Function to your Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: can you add how many memory is assigned to your function? and are you using vpc servless or public IP to reach your cloud sql instance? is your function using SSL certificate to connect with your SQL instance?

Comment: 1) Using Hikari Config with connection string **jdbc:mysql:///<DB_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=<DB_USER>&password=<DB_PASS>**      2) 256MB, No VPN and Public IP access is enabled for database management from my local machine is enabled.  I am seeing this Log, `Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [<INSTANCE_NAME>] via SSL socket`  **Any significance of that ?????**

Comment: There is not any issue on your configuration, if your connection to the instance is working well, but you want to know more about this logs it is better to  open an issue on the cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory [github page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/issues) this is to find out why these exceptions were triggered

Comment: Thanks @JAHernadez raised the issue. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/issues/310